# SMTP problems using IIS and PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have php code  for SMTP. It shows all information when I submit in the website, but the description shows me undefined

Here is the code of php mailing:

```
   <div class='view_group' style='padding: 20px 10px;box-sizing: border-box;'>
   <h4 style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;margin: 0; margin-bottom: 7px; font-size:14px;'>
     PROJECT BRIEF DESCRIPTION
   </h4>
   <p style='font-family: monospace;margin: 0;'>$description</p>
```

Comment: Presumably `$description` is undefined, then. We can't tell you why that is, because you didn't show how/where you think that variable is being given a value, or how that then feeds into the HTML snippet you've provided. Have you tried to trace that? Do you understand how to debug your code? Try some simple debugging, and if you're still stuck, [edit] your question to provide a [mre] of the issue so that we can see how you populate $description, and also provide us any relevant sample data we might need to input into the script to test it. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: You might also want to amend your title to be more relevant and descriptive of the actual issue, because as far as I can tell from your description, the issue is about an undefined PHP variable, and that has absolutely nothing to do with IIS or SMTP, and probably very little to do with PHPMailer directly either.